# Can a template parameter's default argument be specialized?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, traits

In C++, if I have a template parameter, how can I cleanly specialize a default argument? For example, consider the following:

```
template <class Key, class Value = int > class Association;
```

What if I want `Value` to instead default to `float` for class `Special`?  Is there a way to in effect specialize the class `Association` such that if Key is `Special` that Value defaults to instead be `float`?

I imagine one way to do this would be with traits:

```
template <class Key> struct Traits {
  typedef int defaultValue;
}
template<> struct Traits<Special> {
  typedef float defaultValue;
}
template <class Key, class Value = Traits<Key>::defaultValue> class Association;
```

Is there a more succinct way of doing this that is not so involved and would more readily show that int is the normal default at the place where Association is defined?

Comment: I believe there should be a way to achieve what you want with template aliases (`using`) but I don't have time to figure it out

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, a not-necessarily-prettier one-liner:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Key,
          typename Value = typename std::conditional<std::is_same<Key, Special>::value, float, int>::type>
class Association { /* ... */ };
```